# Trackpad collapsed on the right side (unusable) and very risen on the left side. Is this fixable?

Tags: hardware, trackpad

I have a MacBook Pro. After 4-years of use, the right side of the trackpad has completely collapsed. It can no longer be pressed. The left side has risen significantly, but is usable.

Given how a MacBook is built, is it possible to open it up, remove the battery, and maybe tighten some screws (or whatever) to level out the trackpad?

*notes*
MacBook Pro (13", mid-2012)
I've already opened it once to upgrade to a (256-gb SSD) and (16-gb RAM).

Comment: What size MacBook Pro 13" or 15"? What year? Early or late?

Comment: @bret7600 I added that info now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the trackpad is lifting out of the casing, then it is likely a battery problem. Usually costs $200 USD to get everything that has been damaged replaced. This includes installation at an Apple Store.

Here is the price breakdown

- Battery: $130 USD
- Trackpad: $50 USD

Better get to Apple Store. They will likely warranty the new battery for a year just in case it happens again. Your choice though.

If you feel like taking the risk and doing it yourself, maybe see iFixit.com... I have attached [this link](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Trackpad+Replacement/10376) for a [trackpad replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Trackpad+Replacement/10376), and [this link](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Battery+Replacement/10365) for a [battery replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Battery+Replacement/10365).